# Array.prototype.sort.apply( someArray, args ) vs someArray.sort.apply( someArray, args )

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there a substantial difference between the following two implementations of a `sorted_copy` function (NOTE: only their last lines differ):

```js
/* version 1 */

function sorted_copy ( array ) {
    var extra_args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
    var copy = array.slice();
    return Array.prototype.sort.apply( copy, extra_args );
}
```

```js
/* version 2 */

function sorted_copy ( array ) {
    var extra_args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
    var copy = array.slice();
    return copy.sort.apply( copy, extra_args );
}
```

---

More generally, assuming that we have a variable `someInstance` on hand<sup>1</sup>, whose value is indeed an instance of `SomeType`<sup>2</sup>, and that `args` is some suitable instance of `Array`, then when is there a reason to prefer one over the other of the following?

```js
SomeType.prototype.someMethod.apply( someInstance, args );

someInstance.someMethod.apply( someInstance, args );
```

Similarly, if `arg1`, `arg2`, ... is some sequence of values, when is there reason to prefer one or the other of the following?

```js
SomeType.prototype.someMethod.bind( someInstance, arg1, arg2, ... );

someInstance.someMethod.bind( someInstance, arg1, arg2, ... );
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Assuming that all other things are equal*, I suppose that a possible benefit of the `SomeType.prototype.someMethod...` forms is that they may obviate the need to *create* a variable only to get a hold of its `someMethod`.  For example, in version 1 of `sorted_copy`, one could dispense with defining the `copy` variable (i.e. the function body's second line), and just return `Array.prototype.sort.apply( array.slice(), extra_args )`.  The stipulation above that the existence of the `someInstance` variable should be taken as given is there only to take this small possible benefit of the `SomeType.prototype.someMethod...` forms out of consideration for the purposes of this question.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Of course, it goes without saying that the method `someInstance.someMethod` is the one it inherits by virtue of being an instance of `SomeType`, otherwise this post's questions become trivial.</sup>

Comment: There's no strong argument for one over the other when using `.apply()` or `.bind()`. For your `.call()` example, if `someInstance` actually has `someMethod`, you'd just do `someInstance.someMethod(arg1, arg2, ...);`. There's no need for `.call()` at all.

Comment: @squint: Thanks!  I tend to think of `apply`, `call`, and `bind` (kind of automatically) as a group, but on reading your comment I see that the question does not make much sense for `call`.  D'oh!  I'll edit my post to get rid of that case.

Comment: Just so you know, ECMAScript 6 has [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), so you'll be able to do `function sorted_copy ( array, ...extra_args ) {` and then it has the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), so `return array.slice().sort(...extra_args)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.sort.` and `someArray.sort.` (note the trailing dots) is exactly the same thing, so there's no difference. `Array.prototype.sort()` and `someArray.sort()` are different, but that's another question.

For performance reasons, it might be better to use `Array.prototype`, since you can cache it in your namespace, see e.g. [underscore sources](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html).